# Binary search tree two similar functions producing garbage

Tags: c++, tree

I've got this call

```
productTree.displayNode(productTree.newsearchTree(search, productTree.Root()));
```

Calling these functions

```
void Tree::displayNode(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        cout << node->productdata << endl;
    }
}

Node* Tree::newsearchTree(string search, Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        newsearchTree(search, node->left);
            if (search == node->productdata.getName()) {
                return node;
            }
        newsearchTree(search, node->right);
    }
}

Node* Root() { return root; };
```

Which produces a garbage output when trying to display the returned node.

And yet, I can traverse my tree and display it easily this way:

This call:

```
productTree.Inorder(productTree.Root());
```

Functions:

```
void Tree::Inorder(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        Inorder(node->left);
        displayNode(node);
        Inorder(node->right);
    }
}
```

And where I am confused is how are they different?

Edit: Thank you for your help, I modified the code as below and it works fine now:

```
Node* Tree::newsearchTree(string search, Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        newsearchTree(search, node->left);
            if (search == node->productdata.getName()) {
                return node;
            }
        newsearchTree(search, node->right);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void Tree::displayNode(Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        cout << node->productdata << endl;
    }
    else if (node == NULL) {
        cout << "Product not found" << endl;
    }
}
```

Yep, that's still broken. This finally fixed it I believe:

```
Node* Tree::newsearchTree(string search, Node* node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        if (search == node->key) {
            return node;
        }
        if (search < node->key) {
            return newsearchTree(search, node->left);
        }
        else {
            return newsearchTree(search, node->right);
        }
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I am still learning Visual Studio's debugger and I have stepped through it but the errors dont make any sense. The only difference I can see if the if check, though.

Comment: "which produces garbage" - look at the return value type of your function. Now, look *inside* the function at the two recursive calls and wonder to yourself what possible good they will do, as *their* return values are completely ignored. Finally, look at your code again, and ask yourself what is returned along *all* possible exit paths of this function. You only cover one, and if it wasn't the tree root node matching your input param, your function is *guaranteed* to invoke undefined behavior by not providing a return value. Unrelated, searches are generally *pre-order*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a return NULL; after the if and it works fine now.

Comment: @MushinZero Really, and you tested that (the *posted code* in this question with a tree of multiple nodes and searching for a node that is *not* the root node? That case is still quite broken.

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused. Is my edit not correct? It seems to work fine. Also, I apologize if I am not doing the correct traversal but the assignment states to use inorder for searches.

Comment: If it "works", that's great, but the posted code cannot possibly do so unless the node you're searching for happens to be the *root* node of the tree at the time you perform your search. All other cases dive into recursive descent, the results of which being ultimately ignored on the ascension back out of the recursion, resulting in an ultimate return value of NULL. At least that's what *this* code does.

Comment: Oh I see because it will return the node then return NULL in the next layer in. I am not sure how to fix that then...

This is me trying to rework the search tree using in order. I had a solution before but it was like 4 functions and a bunch of if else checks and it seems really awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add comments inline to make it clear what your Tree::newsearchTree does.

```
Node* Tree::newsearchTree(string search, Node* node) {
  if (node != NULL) {
    newsearchTree(search, node->left);  // burn CPU but leaves no side effect
    if (search == node->productdata.getName()) {
      return node;  // return node only if the root node equals 'search'
    }
    newsearchTree(search, node->right);  // burn CPU without side effect
  }
  // In majority of the cases (root node != 'search'): return nothing.
}
```

Because typically newsearchTree() returns nothing, when you call productTree.displayNode(productTree.newsearchTree(...)) you basically print garbage.

Comment: Thank you, I feel dumb now but I've never seen garbage before so I wasn't sure what was going on.